# TFS Devops. Can not find the external project file

Tags: tfs, devops

I have a c# solution with external project added. This external project is in another TFS Project, then when I generate the build, TFS show next error

> "Error MSB3202: The project file can not be found "...csproj".

In the GetSource step (Before Agent Job), i can't add this project because it's in another TFS Project.

The structure is like this:

```
TFS Collection
 ... TFS Project Main
     ... Branch 1
         ... Solution 1
 ... TFS Another Project
     ... Branch 2
         ... Solution 2
```

Solution 2 has Project 2.
Solution 1 has Project 1 and add Existing Project 2.

Is it possible build Solution 1 in TFS Devops?

I work with Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2018.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you use GIT or TFVC?

Comment: Hi Shayki. I use TFVC.

Comment: So you can take both projects source code in one build, see my answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that if two projects share source code, it's considered a very poor practice to put them in separate team projects. Think of a team project as a portfolio of related code.

Comment: I know, Daniel, but it's an existing solution and I can not move both solutions in the same TFS Project due to the business plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the sources in the build definition on Project 1 you can select the files from Project 2 (even if it's a different TFS project):
[image]

Now in the build agent you have both projects and you can build all.

Comment: Hi Shayki,

TFS has only these options: "This Project", "Remote Repository" and "Subversion".

Your image is in Azure Devops.

Thanks

Comment: In TFS 2018 the screen should be like in my image or similar, you can choose TFVC repo from another project.

Comment: @AlbertodeVargas It's ok, choose on the left icon, then in the "Server path" after the `$/` you can write name of another project, and it will work! TFS will download to the agent also the code from the second project. I just tested it in TFS 2017, it should works also in 2018.

Comment: You can't choose it in the UI, but if you will type $/Second Project in the field you will see that you will not get an error and the build will get the code also from there.